# Libreoffice writer file format problems, how to change the file format from one to other format, PDF to any other?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

How will I change formats in libreoffice writer, If I have anything in PDF format, then how can I change that formats of same material to formats like Doc and differents?

**How can i change my documents format, If I have saved a document in PDF format, then how can I change that file format to Doc or any other?**

***any help will be most appreciated!***

Comment: I want to change my Pre-saved PDF format to any other formats and i am also not able to make the changes in that file. I also want to edit that PDF file ifo but i am not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can open a file in LibreOffice Writer, then you can save it in any format you like using `File -> Save as...` menu.

But you need to open it from LO Writer

`File -> Open -> PDF - Portable Document Format (Writer)`. You need to scroll down file formats.

Default format for LO Writer is `odt`, but you can save as `doc`, `docx` or other formats.

But not all `pdf` files contain text. Some of them contain raster images that can not be converted to text that easily.

If you saved `pdf` files from LibreOffice, then they should open with no problems. It must be hybrid format.

**Note:** ***`libreoffice-pdfimport` package should be installed. It is installed in Ubuntu by default.***

Comment: have you tried this after loading the pdf file? It doesn't give the option of doc or docx

Comment: The only options I got from LO was .odg, .otg and .fodg. I also tried export but it only either gave me image formats or .html

Comment: It is because it is opened in LO draw by default

Comment: PDF's can only be opened in LO draw and so your solution won't work.

Comment: I open hybrid pdf in writer. Just save a text file from Writer to pdf and open it as I described in my answer. Not all pdfs can be opened. Same is with abiword.

Answer (score -1):

Abiword seems to be capable of this, with a word of warning that if there are equations in the pdf it doesn't do well:

```
    sudo apt-get install abiword
```

Then once installed:

```
    abiword
```

to launch and open the pdf file, then go to file save as, and in the dialog box there will be an option for openoffice (.docx) click on that.

Comment: What is the point in installing abiword that has less capabilities that LO writer?